# How to reboot computer and install updates while rebooting?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-update

I know that one can use `ExitWindowsEx` API with the `EWX_REBOOT` flag to reboot computer, but how do you instruct Windows to install updates while rebooting (if any are pending)?

Like this option:

[image]

Comment: @nhgrif: So there's no special API or registry setting to request installation of updates during rebooting?

Comment: are you making a driver ?

Comment: I don't know.  The only time I've EVER seen my computer tell me to do reboot updates in the manner you're suggesting is when it's been Windows Updates.

Comment: OK, thanks. It seems like I've been using the wrong API. And no, I'm not writing a driver.